# How to dynamically use Arcmain or just partionly copy tables in Teradata?

Tags: sql, database, teradata, database-restore

I need to copy tables from one teradata server  to another one  pretty much tables. In order to solve this problem, I have been advised to use **arcmain**. So table can be transfered this way:

```
logon ZZZZ/YYYY,XXXX;

COPY DATA TABLES

(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME11) (FROM(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME1)),
(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME12) (FROM(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME2)),
(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME13) (FROM(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME3)),

RELEASE LOCK,

FILE=NVDSID1;
```

However I have some tables with same names among different databases,  in addition this table need to transfered just their structure and some rows (let it be `WHERE service_quality ='epic'`). Is there solution how to just partionally copy tables?

Initially, I have been  figured out quite different way:

1) I copy all these tables `s structure to temp database

2) Insert just required rows to them

3) Copy these tables to required DB on another table

But, one more time, tables with same names rune this solution, they just cant be simply pasted to same DB. Is that possibly to do these 3 steps in a loop, adding one  more step - `drop table` to avoid conflicts?

Creating 100 temp DB really bad solution, and there are already tables with 30 symbols long name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we have done in our environment is to build a set of databases where we populate tables containing slices of data that are destined for another environment. This is very similar to your approach except we use multiple databases and don't have redundant object names. We then use ARCMAIN to ARCHIVE these tables and COPY them to the destination environment.

If you have multiple tables that share the same name across databases I would suggest you create multiple databases to seed the slices of data unless the table structures are the same and the intent is to merge the slices on the target environment. Then you can merge the data in these seed tables for your archive process.

Other solutions include using FastExport and FastLoad or Teradata's Data Mover. The latter is likely going to require additional licensing from Teradata if you are not already using it. The former being script driven can be more flexible than ARCMAIN to accommodate the needs of your particular environment.

Comment: Eventually I renamed tables by using 2 temp tables with table and DB names and linked to them Id (IDENTITY), to be able to store them in a temp DB. After that dealing question wont look like a problem.

Comment: As far as I know new Teradata (14.1+ versions) permits 128 long table names, so in this temp DB names can be easily become unique this way:
`Databasename.tableName`

Comment: Yes, but it does require a change to the default DBSControls to enable and, I believe, you need to enclosed any name exceeding 30 characters in double quotes (").